# Cannot read property ScheduleDate from undefined

Tags: javascript

```
 var AppPatientsList = JSON.parse(JSON RESPONSE);   
  var AppPatientsListSort = AppPatientsList.sort(function(a,b){
     return   a.firstName.toLowerCase() <b.firstName.toLowerCase()
            ? -1
            : a.firstName.toLowerCase()>b.firstName.toLowerCase()
            ? 1 : 0;
  });    
    var DataArray = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < AppPatientsListSort.length; ++i) {
        if (AppPatientsListSort[i].firstName === search.value) {
        var appointment = {};
        appointment.PatientID = AppPatientsListSort[i].PatientID;
        appointment.ScheduleDate = AppPatientsListSort[i].ScheduleDate;
        alert(appointment.ScheduleDate); // Works fine, i get the date... 
        }   
        DataArray[i] = appointment;
      } 
      var RowIndex = 0;
      var ScheduleDate = "";
      for (i = 0, len = DataArray.length; i < len; i++) {
        // Throws me error in this place... WHY?
        if (ScheduleDate != DataArray[i].ScheduleDate) {
          ScheduleDate = DataArray[i].ScheduleDate;        
        }      
      }
```

What's wrong with this code, why i am not able to access the ScheduleDate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only initializing the `appointment` variable when you are inside the `if` clause, but you are adding it to the array on every iteration.

If the first element of `AppPatientsListSort` does not have the value you search for, `DataArray[0]` will contain `undefined`.

In the second loop you then try to access `DataArray[0].ScheduleDate` which will throw an error.

**Update:**
Even more important, as JavaScript has no block scope, it might be that several entries in `DataArray` point to the same `appointment` object.

Depending on what you want to do, everything it takes might be to change

```
DataArray[i] = appointment;
```

to

```
DataArray.push(appointment);
```

and move this statement *inside* the `if` clause so that only appointments are added that match the search criteria.

---

**Further notes:** To have a look what your `DataArray` contains, make a `console.dir(DataArray)` before the second loop and inspect the content (assuming you are using Chrome or Safari, use Firebug for Firefox).